# What URL "prefix" should be used to install RPM packages on RedHat 8?

Tags: rhel, rpm

I know you can install RPMs using URLs, for example

```
rpm -i http://mirror.alpha-labs.net/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/rpm-4.11.3-40.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

However, this URL is for CentOS 7.

What URL "prefix" should be used for RedHat 8 x86_64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you are trying to download a package manually -- normally you would install packages from repositories using `dnf` (or `yum`). But if you really need to manually download a package, for CentOS 8 Stream you can just pick a mirror from the CentOS [mirror list](https://www.centos.org/download/mirrors/), for example `http://ftp.cvut.cz/centos/8-stream/` and then the URL depends on which repository the package is. For the `rpm` package which is in the `BaseOS` repository the full URL would be

```
http://ftp.cvut.cz/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/rpm-4.14.3-23.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

But these are repositories for CentOS, not RHEL. RHEL repositories are not public, you need [subscription](https://www.redhat.com/en/resources/red-hat-enterprise-linux-subscription-guide) to access RHEL repositories and you need to register your system using the [subscription manager](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/rhel-subscription-manager).